# How To avoid accepting requests whose parameters are sent through URL parameters in Oracle Apex?

Tags: httprequest, oracle-apex

Basically, a security assessment was made against our application, and they said "It is possible to convert POST requests to GET, and the system does not avoid accepting requests whose parameters are sent through URL parameters. In this situation, some sensitive data can be sent through the GET method and will be processed on the server side."
Somehow they have managed to use or force GET, even though we have used POST to transfer data.

As a PL/SQL developer I have never worked with this stuff and I can't even exactly understand what is the problem. I have read somewhere it is something about "Cross-Site Request Forgery" and someone told me it is called "HTTP method tampering". I would appreciate if someone tells me what is the problem called and how I can fix it.